# Rx Timeout with Select?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
.Timeout(dueTime: DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
 other: Observable.Return<long>(-1))
.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

The code snippet above would return -1 when timed out. However, i need something that allow me to map the sequence, like the select operator.

I think i need something like a

```
.Timeout(DateTimeOffset dueTime, Func<IObservable<TSource>,Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
```

so that i do something like this

```
 Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
    .Timeout<long, string>(dueTime: DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
     other: i=> Observable.Return<string>(i * i.ToString()))
    .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

Can someone enlighten me on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
    .SelectMany(x => DoWork().Timeout(...))
    .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

You could implement DoWork as:

```
IObservable<Unit> DoWork()
{
    return Observable.Start(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
}
```